# setupProxy file in CRA makes react-scripts start fail with Command failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, proxy, create-react-app

I've added the following setupProxy file according to the example in the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually):

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/address',
        proxy({
            target: 'https://zip-cloud.appspot.com/api',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

But whenever I want to start the npm start command it fails with the following error: `error Command failed with exit code 1.`

I have no clue why it's not working. I'm using the newest CRA version and I'm using typescript. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: have you added `"proxy": "****",` to package.json

Comment: No I haven't but wouldn't that be doing it twice? I want to have more flexibility so I'm trying to add a setupproxy file. Do I have to add it the packages.json too????

From the docs:
You can use this feature in conjunction with the proxy property in package.json, but it is recommended you consolidate all of your logic into src/setupProxy.js.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/address',
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'https://zip-cloud.appspot.com/api',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```